# uploading files to laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I'm trying to upload a file in laravel project (in localhost)

In my controller

```
        $attachments = $request->attachments->store('files', 'public');
```

and in my blade files my code is

```
{{ asset('storage/'.$data->attachments) }}
```

the output url is

```
localhost/storage/files/77T7GkfqQlEiqwy91cYUON2JvNfQkYY5fa3XEcv8.pdf
```

Also i Created a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public"

but when i click in the url i get 404 not found

i seen most of old questions about this problem but i stil can't fix it

please can anyone tell me what is my problem ?

Comment: Please add your route and your form code here as well.